# Extracting mathematical equation from a deep neural network in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, neural-network

I have built a deep neural network consist of two hidden layers (6 neurons in the first layer and 4 in the second layer), (11 inputs), and (1 output). Below is the code:

```
net=newff(Norm_inputs,Norm_Outputs,[6 4],{'tansig' 'tansig' 'tansig'}); %% Neural Network with 12 inputs and four Neurons in the Hidden layers
net.divideParam.trainRatio=80;     %% 70% of the data are used for training 
net.divideParam.testRatio=20;      %% 15% of the data are used for testing  
net.divideParam.valRatio=0;       %% 15% of the data are used for the validation  
net.trainParam.lr=0.01;             %% Learning rate  
net.trainParam.min_grad=1e-20;
net.trainParam.goal=1e-30;
net.trainParam.epochs=1000;
net = train(net,Norm_inputs,Norm_Outputs);
```

where Norm_inputs are the **normalized inputs** and **Norm_Outputs** are the normalized outputs:

Below is the output of my network:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCPPA.jpg)

To test the accuracy of network I am using the following:

```
A = net([0.613497 1 1 0.660657 0.675336 0.150442 0.343584 0.162069 0.655799 0.574284 9.83E-05 ]')
```

I am comparing the output of A with my raw data to check the performance..

I tried to extract the mathematical form so I can avoid opening matlab everytime to see the results..

I did the following in the command window to exctract the weights and biases:

```
b1 = net.b{1};
b2 = net.b{2};
W = net.IW{1,1};
LW = net.LW{2,1}; 
x = [0.613497 1 1 0.660657 0.675336 0.150442 0.343584 0.162069 0.655799 0.574284 9.83E-05 ] %Inputs
```

Then I used the following equation to see the output:

In the command window, I did the following:

```
b1 = net.b{1}; b2 = net.b{2}; b3 = net.b{3};
W_ITH = net.IW{1,1}; W_H1TH2 = net.LW{2,1}; W_H2TO = net.LW{3,2};
```

```
>> h1 = tansig(b1+W_ITH*x)
>> h2 = tansig(b2+W_H1TH2*h1)
>> h3 = tansig(b3+W_H2TO*h2)
>> Output = tansig(h3)
```

x: input vector as a column;
W_ITH: weights between the input layer and the first hidden layer;
b1: The biases between the input layer and the first hidden layer

h1: output from the first hidden layer;
W_H1TH2: weights between the first hidden layer and the second hidden layer; b2: The biases between the first hidden layer and second hidden layer

h3 here is a scalar and I did the following: Output = tansig(h3)..

However, the output is different when I compared it with `x=net(input)`
**Any help!**

I am expecting to have an equation at the end that can calculate the output based on the weights and biases!

Comment: If you have 2 hidden layers, it means you have 4 layers, 1 input, 1 output, 2 hidden. Meaning "the following equation" should have 4 calls, each with a different weight and bias. Or, to simplify, you can do `net(input)`, which does the "mathematical equation"

Comment: Actually that's what I did but still not be able to get the correct answer. 
For example x = net(input) does not give the same result when I did that manually.

Comment: So far, the code you showed does not show that that is what you did, so you may need to show your full code to prove that what you are saying is right. Its clearly not, because the last layer should be adding all values to produce 1, and you are not doing so, as you clearly stated.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! 
I trained the network and I used x = net(input) to  test it. 

Then I tried to that manually.. and the following steps are what I did:
>> h1 =  tansig(b1+W_ITH*x) where x: input vector as a column; W_ITH: weights between the input layer and the first hidden layer; b1: The biases between the input layer and the first hidden layer

Comment: Then,
>> h2 =  tansig(b2+W_H1TH2*h1) where h1: output from the first hidden layer; W_H1TH2: weights between the first hidden layer and the second hidden layer; b2: The biases between the first hidden layer and second hidden layer

Comment: Then, 
>> h3 = tansig(b3+W_H2TO*h2) ... 
h3 here is a scalar and I did the following:
Output = tansig(h3)..

However, the value of "Output " is different than the value of x = net(input)

Comment: I have modifed the question after following what you said!   @Ander Biguri